# Printf and hex values

Tags: c++, c, string, printf, formatting

So, I have a value of type __be16 (2 bytes).  In hex, the value is represented as 0x0800 or 2048 in decimal. (16^2 * 8)

So, when I printf this; I do this:

```
printf("%04X", value); //__be16 value;
                      //Print a hex value of at least 4 characters, no padding.
```

output:
0008

```
printf("%i", value); //Print an integer.
```

output:
8

I should be getting 
0800 and 2048 respectively, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that `value` is 8.  :-)

Are you on a little endian machine, such as x86?  I'm going to guess that by `be16` you mean that the value is big endian and you need to swap the bytes.

Comment: Swapping byte order can be done like this, by the way: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=292902

Comment: Ah, ntos(value) did the trick.
I'm guessing that this wasn't an issue for printing out the MAC addresses (ethernet header) because I was only printing out each MAC 1 short (2 bytes) at a time, and thus avoid endianness altogether?

Comment: Good guess! And I too feel I am slowly developing paranormal capabilities from reading SO.